# JavaScript error handling: can I throw an error inside a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Am I allowed to throw an error inside a ternary operator? Is this valid:

```
function foo(params) {

    var msg = (params.msg) ? params.msg : (throw "error");

    // do stuff if everything inside `params` is defined
}
```

What I'm trying to do is make sure all of the parameters needed, which are in a `param` object, are defined and throw an error if any one is not defined.

If this is just foolish, is there a better approach to doing this?

Comment: If you really wanted to use the conditional statement, you could have a function that throws the error for you. `var msg = (params.msg) ? params.msg : _throw("error");` `function _throw(m) { throw m; }`

Comment: It’s not foolish to want to do this and I really wish I could. Just out of interest it’s been possible in C# / .NET for a while now.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/throw-expression

Comment: What calls `msg` after this bit of code? I understand wanting to throw an error when params.msg is not assigned, and was considering doing this, but when I realized this code would assign the throw message to msg, in this case, it didn't seem to make sense to do? At least not for my use case, so wondering about how msg is consumed in a scenario where it does make sense to do.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function foo(params) {

    var msg = (params.msg) ? params.msg : (function(){throw "error"}());

    // do stuff if everything inside `params` is defined
}
```

I wouldn't really recommend it though, it makes for unreadable code.

This would also work (not that it's really much better):

```
function foo(params) {

    var msg = params.msg || (function(){throw "error"}());

    // do stuff if everything inside `params` is defined
}
```

---

Or for a cleaner approach, make a named function.

```
function _throw(m) { throw m; }
```

```
function foo(params) {

    var msg = params.msg || _throw("error");

    // do stuff if everything inside `params` is defined
}
```

Comment: interesting... +1 thanks for providing a different approach. I agree that this is not a good way to do things. I like the multiple `if`s approach better

Comment: This answers the question perfectly, but I don't really feel like it should be endorsed as a best practice. Imho, using 'if' conditional seems more in line with @Dagg Nabbit's implied thinking and the language as a whole.

Answer (score 23):

No, it's absolutely not allowed. `throw` is a statement and it can't be part of an expression.

Unfortunately, I think that's the only way. You can use `if`s without the braces:

```
if(!params.msg) throw new Error("msg is required!");
```

But there aren't any nice, easy workarounds that I know.

Comment: hmmm... I was trying to avoid the `if`s, but it seems like it'll accomplish the same thing. thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a cleaner way that worked for me:

```
const msg = params.msg ? params.msg : ((function () { throw new Error('Message not found); }()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an error like this inside a ternary operator,

```
function isPositive(a) {
    if(a > 0)
        return "YES";
    throw a == 0 ? Error("Zero Error") : Error("Negative Error");
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that you have to throw error... I guess... so it's not doing it fully conditionally as you don't have option to NOT throw here

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple little trick that will throw from a ternary. I am simply calling a non-existent, impossible to ever exist, property on the undefined symbol. I have only checked chrome, and it can be caught and re-thrown as shown if you need it to have an appropriate error message but that is unnecessary bloat

```
try {
  var msg = (params.msg) ? params.msg : (void 0).throwError()
}
catch(e) {
  throw new Error('Params has no msg property')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To build upon @dagg's approach and the `named function` example; Here is the same but with default parameters with ES6:

```js
function _throw(m) { throw new Error(m); }

function foo({ msg = _throw('msg parameter not defined') } = {}) {
  console.log(msg);
}

foo({ msg : 'party people!' }); // :D
foo({}); // throws!
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this while using `fetch`, here's the solution I offer for that particular case:

```
return fetch(url, request)
  .then(response => response.status >= 400 && response.status < 600 
    ? response.json().then(error => {throw new Error(error.message)})
    : response);
```

Note the (inline) block around `throw` which transforms the arrow-function body from a (return) expression to a statement.

Answer (score 0):

building on @daggs answer a cleaner approach might be

```
function foo(params) {

   var err = function () {
    throw "error";
  };

    var msg = (params.msg) ? params.msg : err();

    // do stuff if everything inside `params` is defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible and you shouldn't use an anonymous function for that. You'll break the error stack trace for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting nodejs, you could use this in an expression:

```
require('assert').fail('Bad response from server or whatever')
```

gives:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Bad response from server or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to use an arrow function:

```js
err
    ? (()=>{throw err})()
    : console.log('smooth')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function foo(params) {

    let msg = params.msg ? params.msg : (() => {throw new Error('Something went wrong')})();

    // do stuff if everything inside `params` is defined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your **throw** keyword inside a function. A call to this function will be allowed in ternaty.

```js
"use strict"

const os = { }
os.throw = (...args) => { throw new Error(...args) }

let i = true // anything truthy

const j = i || os.throw("i is falsy")
const k = i ? i : os.throw("idem")

console.log(j, k)
```

Here we can't print `0` or `false` or `null` because it will throw.