# Is there way to throw an exception from an expression besides using functions?

Tags: javascript, expression, statements

Is there a way to explicitly throw an exception from an expression in JavaScript besides placing that `throw` a function wrapper?

`throw` is a statement, statements don't produce values, thus they cannot be used in expressions which operate on values and always produce a value. It's quite obvious that any statement can be put to a function and a function call can be used from the expression. Is there a way to avoid wrapping the `throw` statement to a function and throw from the expression directly?

UPDATE:

Some people say it's not quite clear what I am asking about. Consider a hypothetical example (not for real), this is something I wish worked, but it doesn't:

```
var one = value != null ? value * value : (throw new Error('The value has not been provided'));

var two = value != 0 ? 1 / value : (throw new Error('The result cannot be evaluated because the value is zero which would give a division by zero problem.));
```

Comment: Your real problem isn't clear. What's wrong with `<script>throw 0</script>` ?

Comment: Could you maybe show an example or clarify what you mean?

Comment: Why would you want to `throw` directly from an expression? You would only throw in some conditions -- so why not use an `if`/`else` or `try`/`catch` blocks?... Are you asking for a one-line check?

Comment: Note : I asked for a clarification, I don't say the question is bad. So... +1.

Comment: @CaseyFalk, I am not looking for a one-line check. I am coding in functional style which encourages using expressions over statements for many good reasons. However it's a whole a different story why functional way is better.

Comment: This is an expression which throws an exception and which doesn't involve wrapping : `JSON.parse()`. Maybe it's not what you want but the context of your question isn't clear to me. This is almost always the problem with questions without code : they're vague.

Comment: Updated with couple of hypothetical examples.

Answer (score 0):

No. As you say, `throw` is a statement and statements cannot appear as parts of an expression.

The only way to execute a statement from the evaluation of an expression are a function call or `eval`. Using a `THROW(new Error(…))` function is probably the best you can get.

But seriosly, go with simple, readable statements:

```
if (value == null) throw new Error('The value has not been provided');
var one = value * value;

if (value == 0) throw new Error('division by zero");
var two = 1 / value;
```

That will not only work, but also fit in a line.

Comment: Is there an expression counterpart of the `throw` statement that throws?

Comment: No. There are some expressions that throw typeerrors and so on during their evaluation, but there is no expression counterpart to `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can throw from a ternary! Perhaps some might call my solution a bit of a hack, but it is very simple to reason about.

[throw from a ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34011931/2905130)

```
var two = value != 0 ? 1 / value : (void 0).throwDivideByZero()
```